# How to get "everything after the ://" in iOS `URL`

Tags: ios, swift

Say you get a `URL` from iOS, perhaps

```
guard let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL else { .. }
```

I want simply "**everything after the ://**" as a string.

That is to say, **everything except the scheme**.

unfortunately `.path` will give you something like

> /blahblahblahblah

but I want just simply

> blahblahblahblah/blob/blab+-&abc=+//cbvc/abc=+-%29k/doa

How do you do this in `URL` ?

(Or indeed in `URLComponents` ?)

(Note: I know how to remove a leading character from a string, the question at hand here is about the class `URL`).

Comment: After **which** slash?

Comment: The first slash is the the first slash of `http://` or `https://`. Do you really mean that?

Comment: Is it still an url when you remove the scheme?

Comment: @Fattie: my point is, maybe you can't because then it is no longer an URL. Extracting the string, modifying it and making a new URL (if possible without the scheme) seems the easiest way.

Comment: hi @koen - there seems to be some confusion, I do not want a URL as the result of this process.  I simply want, as a string, all the characters after the scheme.  thanks!

Comment: Self contradictory. You cannot say you just want characters as a string but also say the question  “is about the class URL”.

Comment: hi @matt !  the question is about starting with a `URL` (that's a specific class in iOS) and ending up with a `String` (another specific class in iOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the range of the `host` and create a substring starting with the host

```
guard let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
    let host = incomingURL.host,
    let range = incomingURL.absoluteString.range(of: host) {
    let urlMinusScheme = String(incomingURL.absoluteString[range.lowerBound...]) else { ...
print(urlMinusScheme)
```

Or strip the `scheme` with Regular Expression

```
guard let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL else { ...
let urlMinusScheme = incomingURL.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "^https?://", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
print(urlMinusScheme)
```

Comment: thank you so much. it's incredible you have to construct it like that!

Comment: Fails with valid URLs like htt p://http or scheme://scheme

Comment: @gnasher729 The second, indeed, but a `webpageURL` is likely `http(s)`.

Comment: it's just really incredible that `URL` (nor `URLComponents ` ) really doesn't offer a way to simply subtract the scheme, leaving the rest !  strange !

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a string as the result, I would get the string from the url, split it in two at `://`, and grab the second half.

Something like this:

```
let incomingURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/blahblahblahblah/blob/blab+-&abc=+//cbvc/abc=+-%29k/doa")

if let components = incomingURL?.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "://") {
   let lastPart = components.last!
   print(lastPart)
}
```

This prints:

> www.example.com/blahblahblahblah/blob/blab+-&abc=+//cbvc/abc=+-%29k/doa